# When loading the header from a folder buttons getting error message

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let myBtn = document.querySelector(".mainBtn");

let myManu = document.querySelector(".manu");

let manuOpen = false;

myManu.style.marginTop="-200px";

function menuFunction() {
    if(manuOpen == false) {    myManu.style.marginTop = "0px";
        manuOpen = true;
    }
    else if (manuOpen == true) {
        myManu.style.marginTop = "-200px";
        manuOpen = false;
    }
}

myBtn.onclick = menuFunction;
```

```css
.mainBtn {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mainBtn:hover {
    background: yellow;
}

.social {
    margin-right: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.manuSection {
    max-width: 1080px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.manu {
   top: 40px;
   max-width:1080px;
   width: 100%; 
   position: absolute;
   background: black;
   transition: ease-in-out .5s;

}

.manu>ul>li, .manu>ul>li>a{
   list-style: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
}

.menuItems{
    display: flex;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 7px;
}

.menuItems:hover{
    background: rgba(134,134,134,0.32);
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
 <script>
$(function(){
$("header").load("asserts/header.html");
$("footer").load("asserts/footer.html");
});
</script>
    
</head>

<body>
<header></header>
```

when the header was in the index.html file the js "menuFunction" was working properly, however, I thought of load the header and the footer from a different folder to each page and took the header piece and loaded to the "header" section..! and finding the js function is throwing an error message..""Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null",".

the header code is

```
  <div class="headerItems">
    <div class="manuSection">
        <div class="socialAndBtn">
            <div class="mainBtn"></div>
    
            <div class="social">
             <img src="https://picsum.photos/40/40?random=1" alt="">
             <img src="https://picsum.photos/40/40?random=2" alt="">
             <img src="https://picsum.photos/40/40?random=3" alt="">
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="manu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><span class="menuItems">Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span class="menuItems">Services</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span class="menuItems">Products</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span class="menuItems">Contact</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="title"><h1>My Business Name</h1></div>
    <div class="telephone"><h2>416 999 9999</h2></div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the browser reads the js code, especially `document.querySelector(".mainBtn")` and `document.querySelector(".manu")` the content of the header has not been loaded yet, hence the error message. [`load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method can take a callback function as second argument, this function will be executed once the file has been loaded. My advise is to move your js code within this callback, like so…

```
$("header").load("asserts/header.html", function () {
    let myBtn = document.querySelector(".mainBtn");
    let myManu = document.querySelector(".manu");
    let manuOpen = false;
    myManu.style.marginTop = "-200px";
    myBtn.onclick = menuFunction;

    function menuFunction() {
        if (manuOpen == false) {
            myManu.style.marginTop = "0px";
            manuOpen = true;
        } else if (manuOpen == true) {
            myManu.style.marginTop = "-200px";
            manuOpen = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the advice and sorry I am not sure where should I insert this piece of code? I mean in the HTML header or JS file -Thanks

Comment: In your code replace `$("header").load("asserts/header.html");` by the code in the answer + from the JS code you gave us delete everything (it has been move inside the callback) except the `function menuFunction() {…}`

Comment: I edited like  <script>
  
$(function(){
 $("header").load("asserts/header.html", function(){ 
  let myBtn = document.querySelector(".mainBtn");
  let myManu = document.querySelector(".manu");
  let manuOpen = false;
  myManu.style.marginTop="-200px";
  myBtn.onclick = menuFunction;
});
$("footer").load("asserts/footer.html");
});
   
</script>  Still it's not working

Comment: Inside the function `menuFunction` there are `manuOpen` and `myManu` which are declare with `let` (those variables are scope to the block). Try with the function `menuFunction` inside the block (I've updated the answer)

Comment: It's working Sir..! Thank you so much, really appreciate and wish you all the best for your future endeavors.

Comment: Thx, same for you, may I ask you to accept the answer

Comment: I am sorry, I could not find the place to accept the answer....:(